# Updating multiple rows in one table based on multiple rows in a second

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables, table1 and table2, both of which contain columns that store postgis geometries.  What I want to do is see where the geometry stored in any row of table2 geometrically intersects with the geometry stored in any row of table1 and update a count column in table1 with the number of intersections.  Therefore, if I have a geometry in row 1 of table1 that intersects with the geometries stored in 5 rows in table2, I want to store a count of 5 in a separate column in table one.  The tricky part for me is that I want to do this for every row of column 1 at the same time.

I have the following:

```
UPDATE circles SET intersectCount = intersectCount + 1 FROM rectangles 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(cirlces.geom, rectangles.geom);
```

...which doesn't seem to be working.  I'm not too familiar with postgres (or sql in general) and I'm wondering if I can do this all in one statement or if I need a few.  I have some ideas for how I would do this with multiple statements (or using for loop) but I'm really looking for a concise solution.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the "final" SQL, your are posting the code by which you generate it (dangerously, BTW), and this does not add anything and makes it more difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
update t1 set ctr=helper.ctr
from (
  select t1.id, count(*) as cnt
  from t1, t2
  where st_intersects(t1.col, t2.col)
  group by t1.id
) helper
where helper.id=t1.id
```

?

btw: Your version does not work, because a row can get updated only once in a single update statement.